# VS code showing additional information in Ubuntu

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Please refer to image.

[image]

Check the highlighted content in the line 18.

When I add the constructor to the code, **year:** **month**: & **day:** automatically appear in the line 18 where I created the object.

This happens only in Ubuntu OS which I recently installed as a dual boot setup. I ran the code on Windows 10 VS code and this didn't happen. VS code extensions are identical in both operating systems.

How can I disable that?

Comment: You can disable it by setting `editor.inlayHints` to `off`. Search `editor.inlayHints` in your config, then set it `off`.

Comment: Worked ! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: why do we get this question every 2-3 days

Comment: I searched, but couldn't find a similar thread. Im not a native English speaker, so my lack of proper wording might have resulted in no similar questions. If this is a new development, Microsoft might have rolled out that feature enabled by default in a recent build. 

I didnt have this issue when using VS code in windows 11 which was installed couple of months back. This was enabled by default when I installed VS code in Ubuntu yesterday. Could also be a default feature specific to OS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inline hint for the code.

Add the following configuration in setting to turn it off directly.

```json
        "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
```

Or use the following configuration to turn off inline hints for java individually.

```json
    "[java]": {
        "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
    },
```

Or use the following configuration to turn off java's inline hints.

```json
    "java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "none",
```

It is also possible to customize the display of inline prompts for Java using the following configuration.

```json
    "java.inlayHints.parameterNames.exclusions": [
        "(arg*)"
    ],
```